# ng-repeat not repeating over array

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting into angular, but am coming across a wacky problem. I'm sure I'm making a dumb mistake, but don't know what it is.

In my controller, I do the following ->

```
angular.module('foo')
  .controller('AdminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http'], (s, $http) ->
    s.foo = []

    $http
      method: 'GET'
      url: cfg.api '/foo'
    .success (data) ->
      s.foo = _(data).map (item) ->
          wid: item
```

Then in html, I write ->

```
 <li ng-repeat"bar in foo">
    <p>{{foo}}</p>
 </li>
```

I'm expecting for li to print out bar.length times, but it actually only prints out once.

This made me think that foo wasn't a proper array, but `{{foo}}` returns

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="bar in foo">
   <p>{{bar}}</p> 
</li>
```

try this?

Comment: oh my god... this is embarassing. Thank you com3lius!

Comment: For ref. The problem was with the ng-repeat"bar in foo", forgot the equal sign!